# How to improve a timeline sql query

Tags: sql, oracle

I have to build an Oracle sql query that aggregates the data over the last day in chunks of 15 min.
I found a working solution, but I am not sure, if I have made a simple problem more complicated 
than it actualy is.

To keep things simple, this is the table i want to use in my report:

```
select 1 as reportval, sysdate - 1/5 as dc from dual
                        union
                        select 3, sysdate - 1/3 from dual
                        union
                        select 4, sysdate - 1/5 from dual
                        union
                        select 5, sysdate - 1/4 from dual
```

So I build a query to get a timeline of the last day:

```
SELECT LEVEL
                   , CASE
                        WHEN CAST (
                                TO_CHAR (SYSDATE - ( (60 / 86400) * LEVEL * 15)
                                       , 'MI') AS NUMBER) BETWEEN 0
                                                              AND 14 THEN
                              TO_CHAR (SYSDATE - ( (60 / 86400) * LEVEL * 15)
                                     , 'ddmmyyyyHH24')
                           || '00'
                        WHEN CAST (
                                TO_CHAR (SYSDATE - ( (60 / 86400) * LEVEL * 15)
                                       , 'MI') AS NUMBER) BETWEEN 15
                                                              AND 29 THEN
                              TO_CHAR (SYSDATE - ( (60 / 86400) * LEVEL * 15)
                                     , 'ddmmyyyyHH24')
                           || '15'
                        WHEN CAST (
                                TO_CHAR (SYSDATE - ( (60 / 86400) * LEVEL * 15)
                                       , 'MI') AS NUMBER) BETWEEN 30
                                                              AND 44 THEN
                              TO_CHAR (SYSDATE - ( (60 / 86400) * LEVEL * 15)
                                     , 'ddmmyyyyHH24')
                           || '30'
                        WHEN CAST (
                                TO_CHAR (SYSDATE - ( (60 / 86400) * LEVEL * 15)
                                       , 'MI') AS NUMBER) BETWEEN 45
                                                              AND 59 THEN
                              TO_CHAR (SYSDATE - ( (60 / 86400) * LEVEL * 15)
                                     , 'ddmmyyyyHH24')
                           || '45'
                     END
                        AS timeinterval
                FROM DUAL
          CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 96
```

and combined it with my report table.

```
-- aggregate data for report
select sum(qry3.reportval), qry1.chunkid from  

-- timeline
  (SELECT LEVEL
                   , CASE
                        WHEN CAST (
                                TO_CHAR (SYSDATE - ( (60 / 86400) * LEVEL * 15)
                                       , 'MI') AS NUMBER) BETWEEN 0
                                                              AND 14 THEN
                              TO_CHAR (SYSDATE - ( (60 / 86400) * LEVEL * 15)
                                     , 'ddmmyyyyHH24')
                           || '00'
                        WHEN CAST (
                                TO_CHAR (SYSDATE - ( (60 / 86400) * LEVEL * 15)
                                       , 'MI') AS NUMBER) BETWEEN 15
                                                              AND 29 THEN
                              TO_CHAR (SYSDATE - ( (60 / 86400) * LEVEL * 15)
                                     , 'ddmmyyyyHH24')
                           || '15'
                        WHEN CAST (
                                TO_CHAR (SYSDATE - ( (60 / 86400) * LEVEL * 15)
                                       , 'MI') AS NUMBER) BETWEEN 30
                                                              AND 44 THEN
                              TO_CHAR (SYSDATE - ( (60 / 86400) * LEVEL * 15)
                                     , 'ddmmyyyyHH24')
                           || '30'
                        WHEN CAST (
                                TO_CHAR (SYSDATE - ( (60 / 86400) * LEVEL * 15)
                                       , 'MI') AS NUMBER) BETWEEN 45
                                                              AND 59 THEN
                              TO_CHAR (SYSDATE - ( (60 / 86400) * LEVEL * 15)
                                     , 'ddmmyyyyHH24')
                           || '45'
                     END
                        AS chunkid
                FROM DUAL
          CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 96) qry1          
-- report data          
          , (SELECT qry2.reportval
               , CASE
                    WHEN CAST (TO_CHAR (qry2.dc, 'MI') AS NUMBER) BETWEEN 0
                                                                                AND 14 THEN
                          TO_CHAR (qry2.dc, 'ddmmyyyyHH24')
                       || '00'
                    WHEN CAST (TO_CHAR (qry2.dc, 'MI') AS NUMBER) BETWEEN 15
                                                                                AND 29 THEN
                          TO_CHAR (qry2.dc, 'ddmmyyyyHH24')
                       || '15'
                    WHEN CAST (TO_CHAR (qry2.dc, 'MI') AS NUMBER) BETWEEN 30
                                                                                AND 44 THEN
                          TO_CHAR (qry2.dc, 'ddmmyyyyHH24')
                       || '30'
                    WHEN CAST (TO_CHAR (qry2.dc, 'MI') AS NUMBER) BETWEEN 45
                                                                                AND 59 THEN
                          TO_CHAR (qry2.dc, 'ddmmyyyyHH24')
                       || '45'
                 END as chunkid
                    from (select 1 as reportval, sysdate - 1/5 as dc from dual
                        union
                        select 3, sysdate - 1/3 from dual
                        union
                        select 4, sysdate - 1/5 from dual
                        union
                        select 5, sysdate - 1/4 from dual)qry2) qry3                        
                        where qry1.chunkid = qry3.chunkid (+)                        
                      group by qry1.chunkid order by qry1.chunkid
```

Any ideas, how i could rewrite the query?

Comment: I see (an) un-necessary close vote.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way to avoid doing all the CASE and TO_CHAR is to use the INTERVAL DAY TO SECOND datatype.  Your can get a timeline query like this:

```
select level chunkid
     , trunc(sysdate)
         + numtodsinterval(15 * (level-1), 'minute') interval_from
     , trunc(sysdate)
         + numtodsinterval(15 * (level), 'minute')
         - interval '1' second interval_to
  from dual
 connect by level <= 96
```

15 minutes multiplied by level-1 gives the start of each 15 minute interval.

15 minutes multiplied by level and then subtracting 1 second gives the end of the 15 minute interval (at least when using DATE, it won't work like this if you are using TIMESTAMP.)

And then you can join to your datatable using BETWEEN:

```
with intervals as (
   select level chunkid
        , trunc(sysdate)
            + numtodsinterval(15 * (level-1), 'minute') interval_from
        , trunc(sysdate)
            + numtodsinterval(15 * (level), 'minute')
            - interval '1' second interval_to
     from dual
    connect by level <= 96
), datatable as (
   select 1 as reportval, sysdate - 1/5 as dc from dual
   union all
   select 3, sysdate - 1/3 from dual
   union all
  select 4, sysdate - 1/5 from dual
   union all
   select 5, sysdate - 1/4 from dual
)
select i.chunkid
     , sum(d.reportval)
  from intervals i
  left outer join datatable d
      on d.dc between i.interval_from and i.interval_to
 group by i.chunkid
 order by i.chunkid
```

In case you are using TIMESTAMP rather than DATE, then skip subtracting the one second in the intervals query and then instead of BETWEEN in the join you can use >= interval_from and < interval_to .

If you do not have a use for the chunkid, you can skip it altogether:

```
with intervals as (
   select trunc(sysdate)
            + numtodsinterval(15 * (level-1), 'minute') interval_from
        , trunc(sysdate)
            + numtodsinterval(15 * (level), 'minute')
            - interval '1' second interval_to
     from dual
    connect by level <= 96
), datatable as (
   select 1 as reportval, sysdate - 1/5 as dc from dual
   union all
   select 3, sysdate - 1/3 from dual
   union all
   select 4, sysdate - 1/5 from dual
   union all
   select 5, sysdate - 1/4 from dual
)
select i.interval_from
     , sum(d.reportval)
  from intervals i
  left outer join datatable d
      on d.dc between i.interval_from and i.interval_to
 group by i.interval_from
 order by i.interval_from
```

Hope this is useful :-)